# getting error when run npm start command with gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

When I run command `npm start` it's giving me error

> ERROR
>
> gatsby develop
>
> Start development server. Watches files, rebuilds, and hot reloads if
> something changes

And when I run command `gatsby build` it's giving me this error:

> gatsby  can only be run for a gatsby site. Either the current
> working directory does not contain a valid package.json or 'gatsby' is
> not specified as a dependency

I tried to delete node_modules and install again but still giving me the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not running the commands in the proper folder.

`npm start`, `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` must be triggered in the root of your Gatsby project, where the `package.json` is located.

Share more details about where and how are you trying to run `npm start` and even your project structure in order to know what's going on.